# Crystal Server Enterprise 11

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-server, business-objects-sdk

Is there a way to construct a URL that when the user is redirected to, displays the report. I am running Crystal Enterperise server 11. I have created a folder in which the report exists. I can want to know what the URL should be. I am running the Tomcat web/application server that came with Crystal Enterprise server 11. I can get the token so that the user does not have to login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [URL Reporting](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxir2/en/devsuite.htm#en/BOE_SDK/boesdk_java_dg_doc/doc/boesdk_java_dg/Report_Linking.html).  The 'token' parameter can be used with a logon token to eliminate the need for repeated logons.